# Как создать проверку в setter

Tags: c#, setter

Подскажите почему код не работает.

```
class Person
{
    public int age;
    public int Age
    {
        set
        {
            if (value < 15)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You're not old enough yet");
            }
            age = value;
        }
        get 
        {
            
                return age;
        }
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Person per = new Person();
        per.age = 13;
        Console.WriteLine(per.Age);
        Console.ReadLine();

    }
}
```

Comment: Уточните, а как по-вашему оно должно работать?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
public int age;
public int Age
{
    // ...
}

// ...
Person per = new Person();
per.age = 13;
```

Вы напрямую пишете в ***поле*** `age`, поэтому проверка, которую вы написали в ***свойстве*** `Age` не работает. Нужно запретить писать напрямую в поле `age` (если бы вы это сделали сразу, у вас бы вышла ошибка и вы бы поняли в чём тут дело) и писать значение в свойство `Age`, тогда проверка сработает:

```
private int age; // приватное поле, снаружи в него писать нельзя
public int Age
{
    // ...
}

// ...
Person per = new Person();
per.Age = 13; // пишем туда, куда разрешено - в свойство, а не в поле
```

Кроме того, по логике, если значения < 15 являются недопустимыми, нужно устанавливать значение в сеттере только если значение является допустимым:

```
        if (value < 15)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You're not old enough yet");
        }
        else
        {
            age = value; // проверка пройдена, можно присваивать
        }
```